How many ways can we place numbers 1 to n around a circle such that each number is a divisor of the sum of its two adjacent numbers
Suppose $n$ is a natural number ($n \gt 3$). In how many ways can we place numbers $1, 2, \cdots, n$ around a circle such that each number is a divisor of the sum of its two adjacent numbers?
More formally, count the number a permutations of $n$ where $(a_{(i - 1 + n) \% n} + a_{(i + 1) \% n}) \equiv 0 \pmod{a_i}$.
$a \% b$ is the same as $a \mod{b}$
Note that 2 permutations are considered the same if one is the reversed version of the other.
So I Found out that the answer for odd $n$ is $2$ and for even $n$ is $1$.
I'm struggling to prove this. I'm thinking of induction:
Induction on $n$: We induce from $n$ to $n+2$ showing that the answer of $n+2$ is the same as the answer of $n$.
But I'm struggling to prove the induction step; I was thinking of mapping every possible answer of $n+2$ to an answer of $n$ but couldn't find a good mapping function.
Appreciate Any helps
P.S sorry for the bad Tex formatting couldn't get it to be better
EDIT: If someone wants to see the examples: https://ideone.com/WJopRd

FYI, using an Approach0 search, there are the AoPS threads Divisor of the sum of consecutive numbers in a circle and I need help?.

Hello, thank u for the information, I've visited both threads, One was empty, and the other one said the the answer for every n > 3 is 2, Tho I wrote a code to check every possible combination: https://ideone.com/WJopRd, it counts every permutation twice(itself and its reverse). And the answer was the one in my post  @JohnOmielan

@WillJagy take this example for 5: (5 3 4 1 2), (2 1 4 3 5), (1 2 3 4 5), (5 4 3 2 1).

oh, good point.
